# Domain sharing to another server

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, proxy, aws-vpc

We have domain that registered in a cloudflare by alb dns CNAME record and hosted in windows server as prod server.

on other hand we also had an ubuntu server infront of windows server.

**My question is** can we mask the production server ip or alb dns ip address on checking domain the `nslookup domainname`?

It is possible to show ubuntu server ip address when user check the domain on `DNSChecker or nslookup cmd` instead of showing the production server ip address or alb dns ip address. is there any possible way to change the ip address of domain even its hosted on production server.

Answer (score 0):

The IP address of the server / ALB is typically required if you want people to be able to reach it on the internet.

One way around this is using the [CloudFlare Tunnels](https://www.cloudflare.com/products/tunnel/). It runs a CloudFlare daemon which connects out to CloudFlare, CloudFlare sends connections down this tunnel. Your server doesn't even need a public IP address, though in AWS if it doesn't have a public IP you then need to use a NAT gateway. Using this technique an nslookup will reach CloudFlare, not your server. Your question is somewhat vague so I'm not sure if it will work for you, but it's worth considering.

I use CloudFlare Tunnels for a couple of small personal websites I host on a Raspberry Pi, but my understanding is it's suitable for enterprise use. You should do a proof of concept / validate this before you trust production infrastructure to it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. @Tim I will try this way.